# How to rewrite URL in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi guys i really thankful to you, because i got several solutions from here, like that i hope i would get solution for my current issue.

the URL is like this

```
www.xyz.com/c73-Graphic-Desgin?resultpage=2&aid=1
```

in the URL "73" "2" "1" are values

i tried to rewrite it on .htaccess file like below, but it does not working...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^c(.+)-(.+)-(.+)?resultpage=(.+)&aid=(.+)/?$ template.php?cid=$1&resultpage=$4&aid=$5&search=yes
```

Please help me to solve this issue, and thanks in advance...

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^article/(.*)?$ article.php?aid=$1
#RewriteRule ^knowledge_base/([0-9]+)/(.*)?$ knowledge_base.php?p=$1&cid=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)-article?$ article_detail.php?artid=$1

RewriteRule ^t([0-9]+)-(.+)/?$ temlate_detail.php?tid=$1

RewriteRule ^c([0-9]+)-sc([0-9]+)-(.+)/?$ templates.php?cid=$1&&scid=$2
RewriteRule ^c([0-9]{1,2})[a-zA-Z-]+?resultPage=([0-9]+)&aid=([0-9]+)$ templates.php?cid=$1


RewriteRule ^ac([0-9]+)-(.+)/?$ articles.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^p-(.*)$ pages.php?pageid=$1

#For PHP files:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(index|about|faq|freelancers|articles|contact|affiliates|login|forgot_password|change_password|cart|order_view|checkout|checkout_response|success|downloads|order_detail)(/.*)?$  $1.php
#php_value display_errors Off
#php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M
#php_value post_max_size 2000M
Options All -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

your regex is wrong.. you can use something like this.

```
^c([0-9]{1,2})[a-zA-Z-]+?resultPage=([0-9]+)&aid=([0-9]+)$ //put here whatever u like to with $1, $2, $3 and $4
```

Comment: Thanks for your Quick reply..

i tried like this
RewriteRule ^c([0-9]{1,2})[a-zA-Z-]+?resultPage=([0-9]+)&aid=([0-9]+)$ templates.php?cid=$5

but its also giving error :(

Comment: https://www.magiktemplates.com/c73-Graphic-Desgin?resultpage=2&aid=1

see the link... its giving error.. sir